# Issue setting up PHP on Virtuoso Server

Tags: php, installation, server, virtuoso, iodbc

I have a Virtuoso server running on Centos7 and have been trying to be able to execute PHP files from an HTML form (even really basic ones just to test), and have had no luck. I found out I had to install PHP and have been reading the documentation from the virtuoso [GitHub README.php5](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/blob/develop/7/README.php5) to setup PHP on the virtuoso server. This is my first time setting up PHP and I have run into an issue when trying to run the `make` command. I am in directory `/etc/php-5.2.10` and have been able to run the `configure` command with all the flags. The error from the `make` command I receive is:

```
/bin/sh /etc/php-5.2.10/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile
/etc/php-5.2.10/meta_ccld -I/usr/local/iODBC/include -Iext/odbc/ -I/etc/php-5.2.10/ext/odbc/ 
-DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/etc/php-5.2.10/include -I/etc/php-5.2.10/main -I/etc/php-5.2.10 
-I/usr/local/iODBC/include -I/etc/php-5.2.10/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/libxml2 
-I/etc/php-5.2.10/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/etc/php-5.2.10/ext/mbstring/libmbfl 
-I/etc/php-5.2.10/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/etc/php-5.2.10/TSRM -I/etc/php-5.2.10/Zend  
-D_REENTRANT  -I/usr/include -g -O2 -pthread -DZTS   
-c /etc/php-5.2.10/ext/odbc/php_odbc.c -o ext/odbc/php_odbc.lo
In file included from /etc/php-5.2.10/ext/odbc/php_odbc.c:37:0:
/etc/php-5.2.10/ext/odbc/php_odbc_includes.h:104:22: fatal error: iodbcext.h:
 No such file or directory
 #include <iodbcext.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ext/odbc/php_odbc.lo] Error 1
```

I do not know if these packages are related but for extra information, I have the following packages installed as well:

```
libiodbc.x86_64 3.52.7-7.el7
libiodbc-devel.x86_64 3.52.7-7.el7
php-odbc.x86_64 5.4.16-36.el7_1
unixODBC.x86_64 2.3.1-10.el7
unixODBC-devel.x86_64 2.3.1-10.el7
```

I have run `sudo find / -iname '*iodbcext.h*'` to try and determine where that file may be located and the only result I get back is `/usr/include/libiodbc/iodbcext.h`. However, I am not sure if that is what `make` is looking for or if there is supposed to be another one within the `php-5.2.10` directory that is used, and if that is the right one, what would I do with it?

Any assistance or advice in getting PHP setup on the Virtuoso server is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The version of PHP you're trying to install is ancient; it was released in June 2009. (It's not even the most recent release in the 5.2 branch.) Why are you trying to install this old of a version?

Comment: I was just trying to follow the version that was presented Readme.php5 file I linked, that's the only reason I was using it as I am not very familiar with Virtuoso as well, so I did not want to stray from the instructions.

Comment: The PHP features of Virtuoso have been [largely untouched since 2011](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commits/develop/7/binsrc/hosting/php/) when they "added initial support for PHP 5.3". ([PHP 5.3 reached end-of-life over a year ago.](http://php.net/eol.php)) I don't think the PHP functionality in this software is maintained at all, and it may be too bit-rotted to use.

Comment: Virtuoso relies on the external PHP libraries, which process the script files, typically from Virtuoso's DAV repository or from the local filesystem. Any PHP 5.x (which is the current production version) should work, and we do recommend the latest stable version. Guesses on SO, as from @duskwuff, tend not to be as accurate as anyone might wish. Hence [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), [public Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/), [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Comment: @TallTed Are you implying that the commit adding "initial support for PHP 5.3" in 2011 actually added complete support for PHP 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, and 5.6, the latter three of which didn't even exist in 2011?

Comment: @duskwuff - Effectively, yes, as is commonly the nature of such external linkages. You may note that Apache and mod_php do not typically require code updates for new versions of PHP, but they do sometimes require rebuilds/relinks with the new headers/libraries. Virtuoso works similarly.

Comment: @TallTed mod_php is a component of PHP (it's built from [php-src/sapi/apache/](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.6/sapi/apache)), so it necessarily gets updated every time PHP does.

Comment: @duskwuff - Yes, sorry, doing too many things, not always writing clearly. I meant that Apache needs no update to work with the latest mod_php.

Comment: @TallTed Right, because mod_php conforms to a particular well-defined module interface, and is loaded by Apache as a discrete module. This component of Virtuoso, on the other hand, integrates PHP into Virtuoso itself using an interface (the PHP SAPI) which is only intended for internal use.

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting packages installed, for the [iODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/) and [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) driver managers.  It is strongly advised that you choose one or the other.  Given that you're using [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) (from my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/)), I'd advise that you settle on iODBC (also maintained and supported by [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), and generally expected to be found by Virtuoso).

PHP doesn't include the iODBC SDK (`libiodbc-devel.x86_64`), which is where the header file `iodbcext.h` would be found.  I should note that the current version of iODBC is 3.52.10, somewhat later than the package you've installed...

It's not clear what options you passed to `configure` to get the `make` script you're running.  You *may* be able to get past the error reported above by editing the second occurrence of `-I/usr/local/iODBC/include` in the `make` script, changing it to `-I/usr/include/libiodbc` ... but this is something of a guess.

Comment: Hi @TailTed, I just was told about Virtuoso's VSP markup as well. Would this be a better way to look into getting my HTML form data to my Virtuoso server than dealing with PHP? So far I have found 14.3 VSP (http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/vsp1.html) page, that goes over some of the basic markup for VSP.

Comment: Also, I had already changed my configure to include `-I/usr/include/libiodbc` for the second occurence, I believe that's how I got past any errors the first time, but then had issues with the `make`-ing it. I now am trying with php-5.6.15, and have removed the unixODBC package, and now am getting `configure: error: Cannot find header file(s) for pdo_odbc` again.

Comment: "Better" is always a judgement call. At OpenLink, we believe in "horses for courses" -- use the best tool for the job you're doing. I don't know nearly enough about what you're doing to say whether PHP (which you may already know?) or VSP (which it's clear you don't know yet) or some other script/markup is "better." Again I encourage you to raise your questions to a broader audience of Virtuoso-knowledgeable people, on the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) or the [OpenLink Support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/).

Comment: About `Cannot find header file(s) for pdo_odbc` I can only guess, because you still provide only partial information.  Best guess is that your `configure` command left something out; I think you need something like `--with-pdo-odbc=iODBC,/usr/local/iODBC/` where you likely had `--with-pdo-odbc=iODBC`...  But I'm still guessing.